# Prefixes in member names of a struct

Tags: c, linux

Consider

```
struct iovec {
   ptr_t iov_base; /* Starting address */
   size_t iov_len; /* Length in bytes */
};
```

or

```
struct stat {
dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

What's the point of prefixing those member names (`iov_`, `st_`)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Once upon a very long time ago (way before even I started programming in C, which is over 30 years ago), the member names of structure elements had to be unique across all structures in a program — instead of 'per structure tag' as the requirement is now, and has been since the days of K&R — [The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) 1st Edition, by Kernighan & Ritchie, 1978.

As a consequence, in those days, the prefix helped segregate the members of one structure type from every other structure type.  Consequently, the habit grew of using such prefixes, and it continues with more recently developed structure types.  The `struct stat` dates back to the days of the old system; `struct iovec` is a more recent invention (maybe sometime in the 1980s) which followed the old tradition.

Using prefixes does no harm.  It could be marginally helpful.  If you see `gadzooks.st_mtime`, you don't need to hunt the definition of `gadzooks` to guess with high confidence that it is of type `struct stat`.

Incidentally, you can find an early version of 'The C Reference Manual' as part of the Unix 7th Edition manuals ([Unix Programmer's Manual Volume 2A](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/v7vol2a.pdf)) which says (§8.5 on p244, emphasis added):

> The names of structure members and structure tags may be the same as ordinary variables, since a distinction can
>   be made by context.  However, names of tags and members must be distinct.  *The same member name can appear in
>   different structures only if the two members are of the same type and if their origin with respect to their structure is
>   the same;* thus separate structures can share a common initial segment.

The same manual documents the long obsolete `=+` family of assignment operators (in contrast to the modern, meaning since about 1976, `+=` family of assignment operators).

Comment: It should not be used in modern code, though. Such prefixes make changing types or refactoring much harder and serve no purpose. Instead of encoding the type in a variable name, one should use a name wich describes what the object is used for, resp. what it contans semantically.

Comment: @Olaf I don't see how you can say that they "serve no purpose". One use has already been given in the answer: seeing the type of a struct from its members' names. Another use is that they're easily `grep`pable, and `man -K`-able.

Comment: @MilesRout: Use the proper tools and those little pros vanish. But the disadvantages stay. With your argumentation, we shouldn't use name-spaces and scopes. Why do you think we have them since decades? If you need to encode the type, do that in the variable name (hungarian notation, also bad practice, see Wikipedia), not the members; they soon become ambiguous in a larger project anyway.

Comment: @Olaf `grep` and `man -K` are the proper tools, IMO. I don't see there being any disadvantages. Could you describe them to me?

Comment: @MilesRout: Comments are not for discussion or to explain. If you don't get the reasons I gave above already, do some research on your own. Sorry, I'm out of spoons. (Just that: why don't you grep for the variable name to see which type it has?)

Comment: @Olaf Comments are for commenting. You haven't given any reasons, and you haven't explained your claim. You made a very strong claim, that the prefixes *serve no purpose*. What do you even mean by 'changing types or refactoring'. I've never ever refactored and found that these prefixes get in the way. On the contrary, they are helpful. And 'changing types' is just meaningless in C, objects cannot change their types at runtime.

Comment: "why don't you grep for the variable name to see which type it has?" because names are highly overloaded, and struct member tags are not.